# Reporting Services Format as number

Tags: excel, reporting-services, formatting

I'm trying to format a column in reporting services to display a number with thousand separator and with commas. The expression I'm using is the following:

=Format(Fields!Price.Value, "#,##0.00")

It works great. Also if I use the expression:

=FormatNumber(Fields!Price.Value, 2, true, false, true)

works great too. The PROBLEM is when converting to excel. The column displays in excel as expected but the format of the cell is General instead of number with thousand separator. As a result users cannot apply formulas to the columns due to is treated as string (General formatting). I know I can convert in excel the column to Number format but I'd like that when converting to excel via reporting services the column just appears in number format.

Is it possible? Searching in google doesn't give me any clues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell what BIDS version you are using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.762 (SP.050727-7600)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Format returns a string so that is what it is converting to in Excel.

To acheive what you want, simply format the item using the Format property. Click on the cell, open the property window and update the Format property to be `#,##0.00`

Even better, to make your application international, update the Language property of the report to be `=User!Language`and then use `N2` as your format property for the cell.

Comment: Chris thanks for the answer. I know Format returns a string, this is the reason why excel cannot make calculations with the column due to excel interpret the columns as no number.

Comment: Chris thanks for the answer. I know Format returns a string, this is the reason why excel cannot make calculations with the column due to excel interpret the columns as no number. This is why I ask for help, I know ho to format as I wish but the result in excel is well formatted but with string format instead of number. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Try my suggestion - if you use the Format property (rather than the Format function that returns a string), the cell remains a number with the right format and can be used in calculations. For instance, using my example above, in Excel I get a number with the format [$-1010C09]#,##0.00

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you were speaking about a property instead of the Format function. I'm going to search the property and test it right now.